# Trajectory By Christoffel Symbols

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

So, basically Christoffel Symbols gives us the components of the vector that represents the rate of change of the basis vectors in a manifold (surface).

And this equation below tells the rate of change of the vector components of a velocity vector summarized by a given object in a manifold where the Christoffel Symbols != 0,

$$\frac{dv^a}{dt} = -\Gamma_{mn}^a v^m v^n$$

Let me be clear with simple terms, $v^m$ and $v^n$ are vector components respectively such that $v^1$ is the x-component, $v^2$ is the y-component of the velocity vector simultaneously.
And $\Gamma$ with indices is the Christoffel Symbol, if you are interested with its derivation I will leave a link below for a video that explains step by step derivation and explanation.

My question is that will this equation hold true for in 3 spatial dimensions where the velocity vector has three components in each direction respectively?

Or it will take the form,

$$\frac{dv^a}{dt} = -\Gamma_{m n}^a v^m v^nv^{i}$$

And $a, m,n,i$ can take value $1,2,3$.
The link to the video:

- ScienceClic English. ["The Maths of General Relativity (3/8) - Geodesics
  "](https://youtu.be/3NnZzRb7L58), *YouTube*, Dec 8, 2020.

Comment: 3 spatial dimensions or 2+1D? Also, where did the $i$ index come from?

Comment: 3 spatial dimensions, by the way $i$ is just a dummy variable we are multiplying vector components by $\Gamma$ because the faster an object is the faster the rate of change of the basis vector increases.

Comment: Nevertheless, Nihar is right and the index $i$ still does not belong. I’m not sure if I understand your question either. The number of dimensions is given $m, n \epsilon 1,2,3,...N$ where $N$ is the number of dimensions. Adding the additional term $v^i$ on the RHS is meaningless.

Comment: The original equation will still hold (but note that this is the equation of the velocity vector of a geodesic curve, not just any curve!). Note that in the expression repeated indices are summed over. The only difference between 3d and 2d is that the sums go from 1 to 3 instead of 1 to 2. Note also that the last expression you write does not respect the index conventions, since the index i appears only at the right hand side (it cannot be a dummy index since only repeated indices are summed over).

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)